# Matlab importdata with tolerance

Tags: matlab

I would like from two input approximative values from columns B and C ​​get the name from column A

Data.csv

```
A;       B;        C
ALGOL;3.13614789;40.95564610
ALIOTH;12.90050072;55.95981118
ALKAID;13.79233003;49.31324779
```

This follow code work fine for exact values:

```
fid = fopen('test.csv');
C = textscan(fid, '%s %s %s', 'Delimiter', ';');
fclose(fid);

val1 = input('Enter the first input: ', 's');
val2 = input('Enter the second input: ', 's');

if(find(ismember(C{2},val1)) == find(ismember(C{3},val2)))
    output = C{1}{find(ismember(C{2},val1))}
else
    disp('No match found!');
end
```

Result:

```
Enter the first input: 12.90050072
Enter the second input: 55.95981118

output =

ALIOTH
```

But how getting the same result with approximate value of val1 and val2? Example: val1= 13.001 and val2 = 57.210 will give => "ALIOTH"

Maybe I have to use importdata and then check with tolerance, but I don't know how.
Is there a way to do this?

Comment: How do you define approximate? What is the precision? Do you always want to map any two numbers to the closest point, or they have to be within a certain fixed range?

Comment: I need to find the closest point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Use floating-point numbers!

Instead of reading your data as strings, I suggest that you read your data as floating-point numbers, *i.e*:

```
C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f', 'Delimiter', ';', 'HeaderLines', 1);
```

This will enable you to perform numerical comparisons. Then you can calculate the distance (let's say [Euclidean distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance)) between the searched values and every row in your data matrix:

```
v = [val1, val2];
dist = sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [C{2:3}], v) .^ 2, 2));
```

Then you can pick the minimal values from `dist` (which will always guarantee a match):

```
tf = (dist - min(dist) < eps);
```

or pick values below a certain threshold:

```
tol = 2; %// Tolerance of your choice
tf = (dist < tol);
```

The resulting logical (boolean) vector `tf` should have "1"s at the positions of the matching rows.

You can convert this into actual values from the first column by writing:

```
result = C{1}(tf)
```

#### Generalization

This solution can be generalized for any number of columns P in your data. Also, suppose that you want to search for several different instances of `v` in your data (let's assume that `v` is an M×P matrix, where each row in `v` is a different instance to be matched):

```
vv = permute(v, [3 2 1]);
dist = permute(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [C{2:end}], vv) .^ 2, 2)), [1 3 2]);
```

Again, you can either pick the minimum values, ensuring a match:

```
tf = (abs(bsxfun(@minus, dist, min(dist))) < eps);
```

or set a threshold:

```
tf = (dist < tol);
```

Here `tf` is a logical M×N matrix (N being the total number of rows in your data), where each column indicates the matching data rows to the corresponding row in `v`.

To convert this into values from the first column, you'll have to store the output in cell arrays:

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)C{1}(tf(:, x)), 1:size(tf, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

#### Example

```
v = [13, 57.2; 13, 47]; %// Entries to search

vv = permute(v, [3 2 1]);
dist = permute(sqrt(sum(bsxfun(@minus, [C{2:end}], vv) .^ 2, 2)), [1 3 2])
tf = bsxfun(@minus, dist, min(dist)) < eps;
```

This results in:

```
tf =
     0     0
     1     0
     0     1
```

which means that the first row of `v` matches to the second data row, and the second row in `v` matches the third data row. To find the matching values from the first data column, we do:

```
result = arrayfun(@(x)C{1}(tf(:, x)), 1:size(tf, 2), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

producing the following cell array:

```
result =
    { 'ALIOTH' }
    { 'ALKAID' }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have a tolerance for how far a pair of numbers can be from either of the target, this is one way of doing it:

```
function testApproximate
    % define tolerance
    tolerance = 1;
    % open file
    fid = fopen('Data.csv');
    % read headers and discard
    textscan(fid, '%s %s %s', 1, 'delimiter', ';');
    % read rest of the data, combine columns 2 and 3 into a single matrix
    C = textscan(fid, '%s %f %f', 'delimiter', ';', 'CollectOutput', 1);
    % close file
    fclose(fid);

    % ask user for values
    val1 = input('Enter the first input: ');
    val2 = input('Enter the second input: ');

    % use Euclidean distance to find the closest point within tolerance 
    x = isApproximatelyEqual(C{2}, [val1, val2], tolerance);
    if x > 0
        output = C{1}{x}
    else
        disp('No match found!');
    end
end

function x = isApproximatelyEqual(vectors, member, tol)
    % set default tolerance if it is not provided
    if nargin < 3, tol = Inf; end
    % v is the difference between all points in vectors and our single
    % point in member
    v = vectors - repmat(member, size(vectors,1), 1);
    % find the minimum value and index of square root of sum of square of
    % all difference vectors
    [mn, x] = min(sqrt(diag(v * v')));
    % if minimum value does not meet tolerance, reset x
    if mn > tol
        x = 0;
    end
    % return x
    return
end
```

This method uses Euclidean distance to find the closest point. If you need to check each value separately to see if they are within tolerance, replace the `isApproximatelyEqual` function above with:

```
function x = isApproximatelyEqual(vectors, member, tol)
    % set default tolerance if it is not provided
    if nargin < 3, tol = Inf; end
    % v is the difference between all points in vectors and our single
    % point in member
    v = vectors - repmat(member, size(vectors,1), 1);
    % return the first pair of points that matches the tolerance
    x = find(all(abs(v') < tol), 1);
    return
end
```

Comment: thks Bee. I tested with values: val1= 16.49012719;
val2 = -26.43202825; when calculate v = vectors - repmat(member, size(vectors,1), 1); I define tolerance tol = 0.1; I get this error message Error "using ==> minus Matrix dimensions must agree".

Comment: I tested with your numbers and I get "No match found", which is expected. Are you sure you have changed the way `textscan` is retrieving your numbers the way it's shown in my code? The top part of my code is different from your original code.